# How to stream a file without saving it down first?

Tags: node.js, express, json2csv

I have put together the below code that creates a CSV called `example.csv`, using the `json2csv` library.

I would prefer to not have to save down and store the CSV file before it is passed to the front end to be downloaded.

I can't seem to figure out how to stream or pipe the file to the front end, without saving it first.

How to take the output CSV file of the `json2csv` library and send it straight tot he front end?

**Some of my code**

```
    const input = new Readable({ objectMode: true });
    input._read = () => {};
    input.push(JSON.stringify(parsed));
    input.push(null);

    var outputPath = "example.csv";
    const output = createWriteStream(outputPath, { encoding: "utf8" });
    const json2csv = new Transform(opts, transformOpts);

    // Pipe to output path
    input.pipe(json2csv).pipe(output);
    
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv");
    res.download(outputPath);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply pipe the `json2csv` stream to the `res` object, e.g:

```
const ReadableStream = require('stream').Readable;
const Json2csvTransform = require('json2csv').Transform;

app.get('/csv', (req, res) => {
    const stream = new ReadableStream();
    stream.push(JSON.stringify(data));
    stream.push(null);

    const json2csv = new Json2csvTransform({}, transformOpts);
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=data.csv');
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/csv' });
    stream.pipe(json2csv).pipe(res);
})
```

Comment: This correctly send the data as a file response. But the headers are named as ['0', '1', '2' ...]. When I set the `fields` attribute from the `Transform opts`, it only send the header row. Any idea on how to correctly add a header to the csv?

Comment: When I use this method I get an extra quote at the end of my output:
id" firstName" displayName"
179 Test1" Test1-179"

Comment: from where it comes *Json2csvTransform*??

Comment: @M.Mariscal: As described in the question from the package `json2csv`.